# If/then calculation within Zap running even when statement is false

Tags: javascript, formatter, zapier

Essentially what I'm attempting to do is circumvent when users enter a number in a non-standard format. For example:

1.5 million should be 1500000

Previous Zap step extracts the number using the Formatter > Extract Number function. So the result is the variable rawNum and the original number is noformatNum.

```
var str = inputData.noformatNum;
var n = inputData.noformatNum.includes ("million");
if (n = true) return {
 finalNum: Number(inputData.rawNum) * 1000000
};
else return { finalNum : inputData.noformatNum };
```

It works in that it completes the operation and turns 1.5 to 1500000, but it executes each time, even if noformatNum doesn't include "million" in the string. I'm not super experienced with Javascript, but after digging around W3C and the Zapier documentation for a couple hours I'm stumped. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I've not used Zapier myself, but you shouldn't have a semicolon at the end of the `if` condition. Also, do you need a space between `includes` and the left bracket in `("million")`? Have you tried removing that?

Comment: @ObsidianAge made those changes, same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a small but significant syntax issue here. You'll want to use a triple equal sign `===` instead of a single `=` in your conditional.

`if (n = true) return {`

should be

`if (n === true) return {`

In an `if...else` statement, the part in parenthesis (the "condition") should be something that evaluates to either a "truthy" or "falsy" value. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#Syntax))

`n = true` *assigns* the value of `true` to the variable `n`, so JavaScript considers the whole thing "truthy" no matter what.

`n === true` *compares* `n` to `true`, which is what you want for the `if...else` statement to work. The value will be "truthy" or "falsy" depending on the value of `n`.